# converting datetime to varchar wrong date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, format

Why am I getting this: 1905-06-28 00:00:00.000 as a result of the following query.

```
declare @report_date datetime
set @report_date = 2013-1-8
select Convert(varchar(24),@report_date, 21)
```

Comment: Use `'2013-01-08'` (for the 8th of January) or even better `'20130108'` to be 100% safe: **[Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
2013-1-8 = 2004 (parsed as days from 1900-01-01)
```

set quotes

Comment: You should accept this answer, it is correct and points out an error that someone else could potentially have.

Comment: aaah! I see, thank you! I'm passing the @report_date as a datetime parameter to the stored procedure and need to convert it to '21' format type. Following gives me an error "Conversion failed when  converting datetime from character string":
    select *
    from  table
    where col = Convert(datetime, ''''+@Report_date+'''', 21)

Comment: Please help with query.

Comment: use this: select Convert(datetime, @Report_date, 21)

Comment: @jim, thank you, I tried it, I get an empty set. In the code-behind I pass the parameter this way: command.Parameters.Add("@Report_Date", SqlDbType.DateTime, 0).Value = rpt_date; rpt_date is a string.

Comment: oh, sorry. i didnt mean to use my text as-is, i meant: select * from table where col = Convert(datetime, @Report_date, 21), i.e. remove quotes from your one here

Comment: probably your rows in database have full datetime value (including seconds and milliseconds) whereas you setting parameter as only date. Thus, datetime 01-01-13 15:23:07:922 is not exactly equal to datetime 01-01-12. In this case you need to truncate dates before comparison or query for values that are in interval from start of the day to end of the day. Example how to truncate datetime to date: select cast('01.01.2013 11:31:16:999' as date)

Comment: yes, the dates in the tables are full datetime values(with seconds, milliseconds). How can I convert the @ report_date parameter which is only a year, month and date into the same format as the ones in the table in the stored proc. I thought Convert(datetime, @ Report_date, 21) would work, but it doesn't

Comment: see example above, compare cast(*stored proc date parameter* as date) with cast(*table datetime column* as date) inside your SP